# Video Reading Problem from Google Cloud Bucket

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to deploy my website to Google Cloud. However, I have a problem with video processing. My website takes video from the user and then it shows that video or previously updated videos to the user. I can show the video on the template page. And I also need to process that video in the background. So, I should read the corresponding video with OpenCV. My code works locally. However, in Google Cloud part, the video is stored as a URL and OpenCV cannot read using URL as expected. According to the sources, the solution is to download the video into local file system:

```
from google.cloud import storage
def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # source_blob_name = "storage-object-name"
    # destination_file_name = "local/path/to/file"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print(
        "Blob {} downloaded to {}.".format(
         source_blob_name, destination_file_name
         )
    )
```

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#code-samples

I have two problems with this code:

1-First, I do not want to download the video into my local computer. I need to keep the video in the Google Cloud and I have to read the video with OpenCV from there.

2-When I try to run the above code, I still get an error because it cannot download the video into the “destination_file_name”.

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Best.

Edit: I solved the problem with the help of answers. Thank you. I download video file to /tmp folder than use with OpenCV. Here is my function:

```
from google.cloud import storage

def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
"""Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
# bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
# source_blob_name = "path/file in Google Cloud Storage bucket"
# destination_file_name = "/tmp/path/to/file(without extension, for example in my case ".mp4")"

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
with open(destination_file_name, "wb") as file_obj:
    blob.download_to_file(file_obj)
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? Limit your question to one problem. You are mixing Google Cloud Storage download issues with OpenCV supporting Google Cloud Storage. Create separate questions.

Comment: Actually the problem is about downloading or accessing the data in the Google Cloud. It is not exactly related with OpenCV. I cannot access the video directly in Google Cloud App Engine. I do not want to download the video to my local system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a duplicate question. You cannot write to the production server in the cloud. From: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime#filesystem

> An App Engine application cannot:
>
> write to the filesystem. Applications can use Google Cloud Storage for
> storing persistent files. Reading from the filesystem is allowed, and
> all application files uploaded with the application are available.

You want to use Google Cloud Storage to upload your videos.

You can write to the /tmp directory temporarily, but that will not persist. But it may work for your need:

```
# destination_file_name = "/tmp/path/to/file"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question. You cannot write to the production server in the cloud. From: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime#filesystem

> An App Engine application cannot:
>
> write to the filesystem. Applications can use Google Cloud Storage for
> storing persistent files. Reading from the filesystem is allowed, and
> all application files uploaded with the application are available.

You want to use Google Cloud Storage to upload photos. You can write to the /tmp directory temporarily, but that will not persist.